# how to convert from cells array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cells

I have 2 cells functions (resulted from certain code) as follows:

```
p = 
      'GO:0008150'
      'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0008150'
      'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0006412'
      'GO:0004672'
      'GO:0008150'
      'GO:0008150'
      'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0016192'
      'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0005215'

c = 
      'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0006412'
      'GO:0004672'
      'GO:0016779'
      'GO:0004386'
      'GO:0003774'
      'GO:0016298'
      'GO:0016192'
      'GO:0005215'
      'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0006412'
      'GO:0003774'
      'GO:0005215'
      'GO:0030533'
```

I have a code that it works fine with single values (numericals or characters), but it doesn't work with the above cellsarrays, and the following error message appears:

> `??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`

If there any idea about how to convert from cells function to any kind which can accept the following code:

```
level1_root=setdiff(p,c) % to find the cells from p not in c
for i=1:length(p)
    a=[p(i),c(i)];
    if a(1,:)==level1_root
        level=a(2);
        level=[level a(2)]
    else
        end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In your code, `a` is a cell array of two strings, while `level1_root` is a cell array with one string. You can not compare cell arrays of strings using `==`. You should rather to a `strcmp`. For example, something like this:

```
  level1_root=setdiff(p,c) % to find the cells from p not in c
  for i=1:length(p)
      a=[p(i),c(i)];
      if strcmp(a{1}, level1_root{:})
          level=a(2);
          level=[level a(2)]
      else
      end
  end
```

However, I am not sure if the above code will work for you as it is. It assumes that `level1_root` has 1 element only. That is the case in the example arrays, but may not be in general. You will have to change the code to suit your needs.

Comment: +1: Darn, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @EitanT sorry, I was just going to sleep ;) so if it is not the correct answer, go ahead ;)

Comment: No no, I was just about to write the same answer as you did.

Comment: @EitanT I understand, but that may still not be correct. E.g. if `setdiff` returns more elements, the answer is not complete.

Comment: Perhaps, but the OP should post some more details about the purpose of the code.

Comment: thank you all for responding... it is working.. and also I found another command named " isequal(a{1},level1_root(j)) (inside for loop and if statement)